# HTTP transport error: Connection refused when accessing web service from Glassfish

Tags: java, jax-ws, glassfish-4

I have two applications running on Glassfish 4.1 server: one that provides jax-ws webservice, and other that uses it. Everything is fine as long as i use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as endpoint in client app. But when i try to install webservice on remote machine and access it, i receive an error in client app:
`com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

However, i **can** access remote wsdl from browser/SoapUI/Netbeans. Service port binding section of wsdl contains valid host:port.

What i tried to do:

- Setting endpoint in client app using

  ```
  (BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointURL);
  ```
- Redo jax-ws import from remote machine, so now even in local wsdl i have remote hostname;
- Changed inject annotation to `@WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "http://remotehost:remoteport/svc/port?wsdl")`
- Checked that glassfish listener is configured to IP `0.0.0.0`

So far, nothing helps. Furthermore, i experiencing same behaviour when i simply change endpoint from `localhost` to actual host name or IP of this very same machine.

Here's the exception log (partial):

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:131)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:223)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:145)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:139)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:136)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.ClientSecurityPipe.processSecureRequest(ClientSecurityPipe.java:198)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.ClientSecurityPipe.process(ClientSecurityPipe.java:186)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:119)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:463)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:191)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy386.processRequest(Unknown Source)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault, turned out that problem was caused by incorrect proxy settings in glassfish JVM options.